# Writing strings and a variable to a buffer in C

Tags: c, serial-port, buffer, communication

I am using serial port to control a device called nano controller. I used `CreateFile`, `writeFile` and `readFile` for communication.

this is the syntax for `writeFile`,

```
if (!WriteFile(hComm, lpBuf, dwToWrite, &dwWritten, &osWrite)) {      
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {   
        // WriteFile failed, but isn't delayed. Report error and abort.
        fRes = FALSE;     
    }
}
```

Here data should be included inside `lpBuf`. It is a buffer.

I want to assign "MINC,moveL" . Here `MINC` are text. however, `moveL` is variable which the type should be double. values should be passed to `moveL` with the time. `moveL` is varying from 0~10 000.

So how do I fill the buffer?

Comment: Two things: (1) show us the declaration of `lpbuf` and (2) when you say that `moveL` is a `double` and you want to write it to the buffer, do you mean you want to write the `sizeof(double)` bytes of the internal representation or that you want to write a text representation of the value of `moveL`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `sprintf` (or one of its cousins):

```
char buffer[128];

sprintf(buffer, "MINC,%f", moveL);
WriteFile(hComm, buffer, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Can you suggest how can I check the content of buffer. I used this.

Comment: @Kumaa: You mean you want to (for example) print out the buffer to look at what it contains? If so, just print it out like any other string (i.e., it's a normal C-style zero-terminate string).

Comment: yes, Thanks for your replies.

I used following to check the content.

printf("\nTSbuffer[5] = %lf ", TSbuffer[5]);

but the value of variable is always 0. please suggest how to check the buffer content. 


I am relatively new for C.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: @Kumaa: Once you've used `sprintf` to put it into the buffer, what's in the buffer is in string format, not an actual double, so just use `printf("%s\n", buffer);` to view its content. If you need to send the double in binary format, you'll have to do things a little differently.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `sprintf(lpBuf, "MINC,%lf", moveL);` to create the string?

Be sure to allocate sufficient memory for `lpBuf` before you fill it with data.